# Use JavaScript to change foreground and background color across the page

Tags: javascript, dom, colors, background-color

I am supposed to display html data in an Android Webview. I am able to change the body foreground, background colour using a wrapper div tag but I still have colour values defined in internal style tags.

Can I use a JS function to iterate through DOM and change all colour and `background-color` values after loading the page?

Initially I was trying to user regex to replace the values but there is a possibility that the data being displayed is HTML which I don't want to break.

Comment: did you try with JQuery or any js libraries?

Comment: JS libraries would probably do it the same way mentioned below; getElementsByTagName("*"). Until the HTML5 getElementsByClassName() is accepted across all browsers, there's no real clean way to accomplish this.

Comment: I am using it on android , thus eont be using Jquery or any JS library.

Comment: @RaviVyas what dose "eont" mean?

Comment: @david its a typo .. sorry , it was supposed to be won't

Comment: @Rob W , thanks for the edits :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a sample script for changing background color on page load for all "divs"  that have background color style. The approach would be needed for all other types of elements that for which background color need to be changed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = onWindowLoad();
    function onWindowLoad() {
        var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
        for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
            if (divs[i].style.backgroundColor != null && divs[i].style.backgroundColor != "") {
                divs[i].style.backgroundColor = "Blue";
            }           
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Although I lost color on the link :)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. You can get all the elements within the wrapper div with by calling wrapper.getElementsByTagName("*") (wrapper being the wrapper element). Depending on the size of the site, that could be slow.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could do something involving a two step approach whereby first you select all the target elements using an appropriate selector (e.g. "`getElementById()`" and "`getElementsByTagName()`") and then set their colors via the style attribute.  For example:

```
// Select all elements whose color must be changed.
var els = [];
els.push(document.getElementById("item1"));
els.push(document.getElementById("item2"));
els.push(document.getElementById("item3")); // And so on...

// Set their new foreground and background colors.
for (var i=0; i<els.length; i++) {
  els[i].style.color = 'black'; // New foreground color.
  els[i].style.backgroundColor = 'white'; // New background color.
}
```

Also, consider using a JavaScript library such as jQuery with rich selector functionality; this could drastically simplify the first step.

Comment: I wouldn't advise HTML5's getELementsByClassName() yet. Depends on your audience though.

Comment: @JeffreySweeney: ah, thanks, I didn't realize that was an HTML5 addition, I'll refine my answer so it's not dependent on that feature.

Comment: The HTML an be anything and I would not be aware of the elements.

Comment: @Jeffrey glad to note, 9 years later, these issues were solved in browsers I use to run MVC5, that is FF and Chrome. I use iit like elements = document.getElementsByClassName("div-diagram") followed by a for next loop, I get all my dynamically created diagram divs and nothing else, no problem..

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend using `wrapper.getElementsByTagName("*").style.backgroundColor = "purple";`. This seems like the best solution given your constrains. Yes, `getElementsByTagName("*")` is going to be slow, but given that this is going to be on an Android device I believe it can easily handle this.